# When will C++ call the constructor on an object that is a class member?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

let's say I have a class

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        AnotherClass myObject;
};
```

My issue is that I want to initialize myObject with arguments to it's constructor, exactly if I were declaring it on the stack during a function

```
AnotherClass myObject(1, 2, 3);
```

but I want to do this for the class member in the constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass() {
    myObject = ...?
    ...
}
```

The problem is exactly that. If I declare a class member that has a constructor, will C++ call the default constructor? How can I still declare the variable in the class definition but initialize it in the constructor?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the *ctor-initializer*.  Members are initialized after base classes and before the constructor body runs.

```
MyClass::MyClass() : myObject(1,2,3) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: GWW's answer is an example of this

Comment: @antlersoft: Yes, it is (we were typing our answers at the same time apparently, he finished a couple seconds before me), but his doesn't answer the title question "When does C++ call constructors for member subobjects?"

Answer (score 8):

You can use an initializer list.

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass() : myObject(1,2,3){ }
        AnotherClass myObject;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Google for *Constructor initialization lists*

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/

Answer (score 3):

```
class A
{
public:
   A(int);
};

class B
{
public:
   B();

private:
   A my_a_;
};

// initialize my_a by passing zero to its constructor
B::B() : my_a_(0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

always use the initializer list:

```
MyClass::MyClass() :
  myObject( 1, 2, 3 )
{
  //myObject = don't do this, bad practice!
}
```

see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6

Answer (score 1):

The best method I can think of is to initialize the member in the class ctor, like so:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int param)
        : m_Object(param)
    { };

private:
    OtherClass m_Object;
};
```

You can then explicitly initialize the member with whichever ctor you want (as well as providing multiple ctors with different params for both classes).

Answer (score 0):

Or provide proper constructors:

```
struct Foo{
  Foo(const Bar& b): myBar(b){}
  Bar myBar;  
}
//...
Foo myFoo1( Bar(1,2,3) );
Foo myFoo2( Bar(3,2,1) );
```

Or if you don't want to expose bar then you can set parameters, for example

```
struct Square{
  Square(const int height, const int width): myDimension(width,height){}
  Dimension myDimension;
}
//...
Square sq(1,2);
Square sq(4,3);
```